# Efficient way to filter part of an XML document

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, .net-3.5

I am looking for an efficient way to filter an XML document. I am using C#/.NET. Say that I have the following original document:

```
<Bookstores>
   <Bookstore>
      <StoreName>Store 1</StoreName>
      <Books>
         <Book>
            <Author>Bob</Author>
            <Title>ABC</Title>
         </Book> 
         <Book>
            <Author>John</Author>
            <Title>XYZ</Title>
         </Book> 
      </Books>
   </Bookstore>
</Bookstores>
```

I have another partial document stored somewhere else:

```
<Book>
   <Author>John</Author>
   <Title>XYZ</Title>
</Book>
```

Using these two documents, I need to output the second partial XML document including its original ancestors.

```
<Bookstores>
   <Bookstore>
      <StoreName>Store 1</StoreName>
      <Books>
         <Book>
            <Author>John</Author>
            <Title>XYZ</Title>
         </Book> 
      </Books>
   </Bookstore>
</Bookstores>
```

I am also open to other ways I might be able to do this. I have an original document that I cannot manipulate directly. I need to store a "reference" to part(s) of that document separately. And then I need to filter/translate the original document using the "reference" for display purposes.

Comment: So you want to make a copy of the first XML document, but filter out all books except the one(s) that are in the second XML document?

Comment: yep, that is what i am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short XSLT solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfReference">
     <Book>
       <Author>John</Author>
       <Title>XYZ</Title>
     </Book>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vReference" select=
 "document('')/*/xsl:variable
                  [@name='vrtfReference']/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Book">

   <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select=
    "self::node()[$vReference
                   [Author = current()/Author
                  and
                   Title = current()/Title
                   ]
                  ]
    "/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()" mode="copy">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Bookstores>
   <Bookstore>
      <StoreName>Store 1</StoreName>
      <Books>
         <Book>
            <Author>Bob</Author>
            <Title>ABC</Title>
         </Book>
         <Book>
            <Author>John</Author>
            <Title>XYZ</Title>
         </Book>
      </Books>
   </Bookstore>
</Bookstores>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Bookstores>
   <Bookstore>
      <StoreName>Store 1</StoreName>
      <Books>
         <Book>
            <Author>John</Author>
            <Title>XYZ</Title>
         </Book>
      </Books>
   </Bookstore>
</Bookstores>
```

**Do note**:

1. **The identity rule is used to copy any node "as-is"**, except for `Book` elements that do not match identical `Book` elements in the reference document.
2. **The template matching `Book` decides to copy the current node** (by applying the identity rule on it) **only if both children (`Author` and `Title`) have the same value as the children of some `Book` element from the reference document**.
3. **Just for convenience I have embedded the reference document into the XSLT stylesheet**. In practice it will be in its own XML file and this would only need a slight change in the definition of the `$vReference` variable.

Comment: Say that my filter had multiple Book records in it though. Would that also work?

Comment: @Matt: Yes, only `Book` elements that are identical to one in the refernce file will remain in the document.

Answer (score 1):

Do try LINQ to XML,
http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx.

I hope this will help.